# JSONP crossdomain call, Handling the response

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am using JSONP call for a crossdomain request as shown below.(using Jquery)

```
$.ajax({

               type:'POST',
               url:sendURL,
               cache: false,
               jsonp: "callBack",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               data:sendData,
//             contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               success:function(data){
                alert(data); //callBack(data, options);
               },
              error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                   callBack(thrownError);
             }


        });
```

This call is made to an LMS from an AICC learning course. The LMS will give a plain text response as below

```
error=0
error_text=Successful
aicc_data=[core]
student_id=826753
student_name=J, Pallavan
lesson_location=1-7
Credit=credit
lesson_status=not attempted
score=24
time=00:00:00
lesson_Mode=normal
[core_lesson]
[core_vendor]

[evaluation]
course_id = {A2}
[student_data]
mastery_score=80
max_time_allowed=200
time_limit_action=
```

I know that the response I got from LMS is not a valid json, so I am getting syntax errors. but i dont have any control over LMS to change the response to a valid format.

Is there a way to manipulate the response on the client side to make it working?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it going in success function?

Comment: No, it is not going in the success function